# Learning to use as3 with XML and PHP but got stuck

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3

So, I am trying to learn how to use XML and PHP to retrieve server info for my flash file. I have gotten it to work sort of. It pulls the information and displays it on my swf file, but it still has the XML nodes.

```
<itemm>example</itemm>
```

Perhaps someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong. I am pretty sure I missed something in the try block. Here is my as3 code:

```
var txtFld:TextField = new TextField();
txtFld.width = 500;
txtFld.height = 500;
txtFld.multiline = txtFld.wordWrap = true;
addChild(txtFld);

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.php");

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);

urlLoader.load(req);

function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
    txtFld.text = "XML load error. \n" + evt.text;
}

function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
    urlLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

    try {
        var loadedXML:XML = new XML(evt.target.data);
        txtFld.text = loadedXML.itemm;

} catch (err:Error) {
    txtFld.text = "XML parse error:\n" + err.message;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing line:

```
txtFld.text = loadedXML.itemm;
```

... for this one:

```
txtFld.text = loadedXML.itemm.text();
```

You have to bear in mind that loadedXML.itemm will return an XMLList, not an XML. That is because what you are executing with that statement is really "give me all nodes of type itemm".

You can see the docs for method text() of XMLList here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#text()

If your loadedXML contains more than one node of type itemm, text() will return a list of XMLList with the text contents of the itemms. If you want to treat text contents individually, you can do:

```
for each(var itemm:XML in loadedXML.itemm.*) {
    trace(itemm.text());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That certainly worked. the output now shows them, but doesn't do the line breaks. I will mark it as answered in 8 minutes :)

Comment: I've added a few more concepts to the answer. Be sure to review them!

Comment: Thank you tremendously, Jotakun!